# php website with node.js daemon concurrently

Tags: php, node.js, socket.io

I am creating a website in PHP (static, preprocessed pages and everything PHP-ish) BUT,

I would like to add some real-time functionalities like, say, a notification function, by using Node.JS with Socket.IO.

So it's basically a PHP website but with a Node.js daemon that pushes some data via socket.io.

I played around with it a bit, and all honestly, it doesn't seem that hard at all.

It's more of a curiosity, but do you think that it might be a good combination to have them together, by adding the Socket.IO javascript on the client to listen to server-side notifications?

Thanks in advance.

---

Also, I noticed that, when I require socket.io on the server, it puts the script on the client side too. As I will not be using node to serve pages, I suppose that the script will not be included in the page. Is there a way to include it manually?

Sorry for my English, I'm not native.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need node to serve pages, you can just include socket.io and connect to the socket server.

In your client, add:

```
<script src="[server address]:[server port]/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

And then:

```
var socket = io.connect([server address]:[server port]);
```